# when making a request, the data is not returning me anything Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I manage to get my slug, and if I return only return response.data.title , it works but when I assign the attributes inside my class it doesn't work

```
import HttpClient from "../config/HttpClient";
import Post from "../models/Post";
import CardService from "./CardService";

export default class PostService {
  private httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor() {
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient();
  }

  public async getLatestPost(): Promise<Post> {
    try {
      const slugs = await new CardService().getSlugs(); // ("ok")

      const { data: post } = await this.httpClient.get<{
        id: string;
        slug: string;
        title: string;
        body: string;
        created_at: string;
      }>(`https://www.tabnews.com.br/api/v1/contents/AndersonVilela/${slugs[0].slug}`)
        return new Post(
          post.id,
          post.slug,
          post.title,
          post.body,
          post.created_at
        )
          
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

```
export default class Post {

  constructor(
    id: string,
    slug: string,
    title: string,
    body: string,
    created_at: string
  ) {}
}
```

I tried to make the request and pull it inside my page in my Nuxt3 project
expected to receive the data specified in the class